# Get members id from telegram channel - pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm doing a bot, in which I want the user to start the bot to verify that the user of the telegram channel. I'm programming in python with the api telebot.

With this I get the user.id of the user:

**idUser = str (message.from_user.id)**

With this I have managed to obtain the number of users, but not the ids to do the verification:

**members = tb.get_chat_members_count ("@ ChannelName")**

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation all api methods are callable but modified to python standards so it would become

```py
memberobject = tb.get_chat_member(channel,userid)
```